# "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: canvas.value.getContext is not a function" in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am a front-end novice. I encountered this error while writing a Vue 3 template:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: canvas.value.getContext is not a function**

Here is my code:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const canvas = ref(null);
let ctx = ref(null);

const drawLine = () => {
    
  ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 400);
  ctx.stroke();
}

const initContext = () => {
  ctx = canvas.value.getContext('2d');
}

onMounted(() => {
  initContext();
  drawLine();
})

</script>

<template>
  <canvas ref='canvas' height="600" width="600"></canvas>
</template>

<style scoped>
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
</style>
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this issue? If possible, I would greatly appreciate it.

I tried in the browser's F12 console. Then the following error appeared：
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: canvas.value.getContext is not a function**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJEcM.png)

Comment: And I tried:

const initContext = () => {
  if(!canvas.value){
   console.log("hello world");
 }
  ctx = canvas.value.getContext('2d');
}

seems  canvas.value is null....

Comment: why is ctx a `ref`? not that you're using it correctly, and your code as shown in the question does not produce the error you claim - it runs quite fine ... perhaps the code you have an error with is completely different?

Comment: https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: that's your code (a little compressed so it can be a link here)

Comment: Thank you! I rechecked my code, and found it was because I used the Uni-app. Uniapp doesn't support canvas.